# Using factory method or not?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, aggregate, factory-pattern

I've written a simple game (turn based, like `Tic Tac Toe`). Architecture is very simple, I have `Game` class which is aggregate root, it has `List` of players and `Board` object. `Board` has `Field` object - typical aggregate pattern (I think..).

Now, there could be few types of this game: Single Player, Two players (on single device), via Bluetooth, via wifi or online (with a stranger). I have two ways to create `Game` object. Like this, passing type in constructor:

```
    public Game(GameType type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        Players = new List<Player>();

        ...
    }
```

There will be for sure differences while adding new player/players. Different situation for single player, different for two players, different for online game. So in such method there must be `switch/case` on type.

**OR, second way:**

Create derived classes, like `SinglePlayerGame : Game` etc... Create class like `GameAPI` with factory method `CreateGame`.

**So,** being in that point, I realized I don't know when to use first way (via constructor and then having `switch/case`) and when use factory method inside additional class..

Thanks in advance for clarifying that!

Comment: An abstract example like this hardly is able to get useful answers, and the way it's phrased it's quite opinion-based too. To give you one: if you've only got two different types of games, I wouldn't bother with a factory anyway, but just `new`  the appropriate game type.

Comment: Hard to tell if it's worth it or not, but it's usually a good idea to [replace conditionnals by polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: @plalx OP already recognized they need that. This question (which is not explained by your link) asks how to then instantiate the class.

Comment: @CodeCaster Right, well the fact is that using polymorphism for game types will ensure no further switches are necessary, but obviously there will be some conditonnals needed to determine the correct concrete game class to instanciante. Those conditionnals should probably be instanciated in a factory.